# How do i transform a factor with comma seperated values to a numeric vector in R?

Tags: r, json, import, numeric

I import my data from a json file and i need some of the elements as numeric values.

the json:

```
[
  {
    "a": 52,
    "b": 2020,
    "c": 14,
    "d": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",
    "e": "4,1,2,3,1,0,0,0,0",
    "f": "TRUE"
  }
]
```

the code for the import:

```
json_file <- fromJSON(file = "file")

json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})

json_file <-as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", json_file))
```

Now what i am trying to do is get the values out of d and transform them to a numeric vector:

```
d_numeric <- as.numeric(json_file$d)
```

The error which occurs is "NAs introduced by coercion" and the issue seems to be that the single values out of d are seen as one level because of the commas (str below). How may I seperate them?

```
str(json_file$d)
 Factor w/ 1 level "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9": 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "Woche"
```

Best regards
tholori

Comment: `help("strsplit")`

Comment: you might try `as.numeric(as.character(json_file$d))` .